# Exporting entity lists to excel gives "Unable to open this Internet site" error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

Ever since enabling CBA/IFD, when we try to export a list to Excel (by looking at Contacts, then going to Contacts -> Export to Excel), it gives us this message after we hit Export, and then Save on the resulting window:

"Unable to open this Internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later."

This seems to work fine from inside Internet Explorer so I'm at a loss here.... I've tried changing the CRM server's headers to include "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" and also disabled Output Caching and set Expire Web Content to Immediately. None of this seemed to help at all

Any ideas what's going on here? I cannot for the life of me find anything about  this on Google as it relates to Dynamics CRM 2011.